# both sided drag and drop listview in android

Tags: android

I have some list views showing some data..now i want to incorporate the feature of drag and drop items in each other list view. I mean i want to drag item from list 1 to list 2,3, and so on..similarly, i want to drag item from list 2 to list 1,3, and so on..
I got some examples of drag and drop..but it is not working for me..most of them are one sided drag and drop list, i mean most of them has 2 list view, you can drag item from list 1 to list 2, but you can not drag item from list 2 to list 1. I tried to implement both sided drag and drop feature, but my try is not enough for me to bring the required action.
Please help with some clue.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is a library in github.

Hope you can get this. https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview